# Magento 2 - admin backend not working correctly in production mode

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, static-content, magento2-enterprise

I switched my store from development to production mode with

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Then I executed

```
grunt clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

But this is how my backend looks like:

[image: backend]

If I click for example on "CATALOG", then usually a slider shows with multiple options, but nothing happens if i click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it is not enough to just call

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy xy_XY
```

You also have to execute it without `xy_XY`

**Solution:**

You always have to call this command after executing `grunt clean`:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy xy_XY && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Replace `xy_XY` with your language code, I use `de_DE` for my german shop.